# Hook into a function without a hook?

Tags: functions, hooks

I have just got into using hooks and have now understand the beauty of them. I understand that I can hook into the following by using `add_filter('hook_name','my_hook_name', $variable);`

```
function a_function($variable){
    return add_filter('hook_name', $variable);
}
```

But what if your the function you wanted to hook into simply returned a variable.

```
function a_function($variable){
    return $variable
}
```

I don't have the `'hook_name'` to hook into anymore. So am I missing something? How can I edit that second function via my functions.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot hook in a function without a hook. If it returns a variable, you will have to use it as it is returned. And then, maybe, perform your operations on that.